# how to set null or no data in mongodb db containing Date type object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I have define an end_time field in my document as

```
end_time: {
        type: Date
    },`
```

So when I update it to

```
    end_time: ''
```

It gets stored as null but when I display it to user it gives

```
06 march 1970 // which i guess is the default date
```

So how to set a null field so that I don't have such problems

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove a property from a mongo document you can use '$unset' when updating the object:

using mongoose the command would look like:

```
collection.update({_id: documentYouWant}, {$unset: {properyToUnset: true}}).exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        //handle error
    }
    // handle response
    return result;
});
```

You should also be able to update a property by setting the value to undefined or to null in the application and saving the object as long as the property is not required.

Comment: I am using findOneAndUpdate and it seems it does not work with that

Comment: are you using mongo directly or mongoose?

Comment: mongoose something like this   mBooking.findOneAndUpdate(updateDbParams.condition, updateDbParams.update, {$unset: {end_time: true}}, function(error, booking_result) {
//                      console.log(error);
//

Comment: {$unset: {end_time: true}} would be your update.
Unfortunatly you cannot run a set and an unset at the same time so it would require 2 calls to do this if you want to update other properties as well

Comment: No problem, hope it helps!

Comment: and for future reference, with update/findOneAndUpdate the params will be collection.update(query, update, options, callback) OR collection.update(query, update, options).exec(callback)